# Unable to import cv2 in 64 bit version of python 3.6.5

Tags: python, opencv

I had installed opencv in python 3.6 32 bit version using the command 'pip install opencv-python', which I successfully used. Later when I upgraded my version to 64 bit as to use tensorflow as well, and ran the same command 'pip install opencv-python', opencv was already present, yet when I tried to import cv2 module, it showed the error that any module named cv2 is not found.

Now I don't understand what to do next. Hope someone can help.

Comment: Please provide details as to, what error or outputs you get when you run `python --version`, `python3 --version`, `'pip install opencv-python'`, `import cv2` and what OS you use etc...

Comment: 'pip install opencv-python' : Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in c:\users\vartika singh\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (3.4.1)

Comment: 'import cv2' : module not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may uninstall previous opencv installation via `pip uninstall opencv-python` then do the `pip install opencv-python`.